# Want to make the add to cart button freeze if zipcode if invalid

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, exception

I am building the ecommerce magento website named "bookslab.in". I want to make the add to cart button freeze if the zipcode of the users they entered in the zipcode field is invalid & want to give the message "Zipcode is invalid, so  you can't buy this product." I am providing you the view.phtml & cod.phtml. Please suggest the changes in the codes that i provided.

cod.phtml

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      zipcode='';
                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

view.phtml

```
 <?php  
    ?>
    <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
    <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    </script>
    <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
    <div class="product-view">
        <div class="product-essential">
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                <div class="no-display">
                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
                </div>

                <div class="product-img-box">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                </div>

                <div class="product-shop">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="price-info">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="extra-info">
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

                    <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                        <div class="short-description">
                            <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>




                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif;?>

                </div>

                <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                    <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <div class="add-to-box">
                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                                <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                    <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <div class="add-to-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
                productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        var form = this.form;
                        var oldUrl = form.action;

                        if (url) {
                           form.action = url;
                        }
                        var e = null;
                        try {
                            this.form.submit();
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                        this.form.action = oldUrl;
                        if (e) {
                            throw e;
                        }

                        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                            button.disabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

                productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                    if(this.validator) {
                        var nv = Validation.methods;
                        delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                        // Remove custom datetime validators
                        for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                            if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                                delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                            }
                        }

                        if (this.validator.validate()) {
                            if (url) {
                                this.form.action = url;
                            }
                            this.form.submit();
                        }
                        Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
            //]]>
            </script>
        </div>

        <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
            <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
                <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                        <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                        <dd class="tab-container">
                            <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                        </dd>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

    </div>
```

I am also attaching the screenshot of my webpage:

[image]

Comment: Add disable attribute on add to cart button if zip code is not valid.

Comment: how to add & where to add

Comment: you use ajax to check zip code is valid or not right ? if it's not valid then use javascript  document.getElementById("addtocart").disabled = true;

Comment: Okzz   i will check & know you is it working or not?

Comment: it will works :) and you can also set message using same method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the button using jQuery

```
if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1){
      zipcode='checked';
      jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // add this code
    } else { 
        zipcode='';
        jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
```

This will work good but it will be client side to disable button. I also suggest you to validate this from server side

Comment: He is not using jQuery and if we can solve this problem with javascript then why load jQuery library.

Comment: and yes I agree that server-side validation is required .

Comment: The Magento version he is using has jquery already loaded. So he wont have any problems with it

Comment: Yeah user3046689 u suggested  me right. But one problem is coming.

Comment: If user add the correct zipcode after the wrong zipcode then page does not getting refresh & the button of ADD TO CART is still freezed. How to refresh the page of product.

Comment: Anyser answer stackys

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: @Priyank can i set the condition like if my Product X present in cart no other products able to add to cart and some other products already present in the cart Products X not able add to cart, the main goal is products X purchase alone. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please ask a new question in case you have a new query

Answer (score 0):

For Temporary you can disable that product with these code

```
<script>
function checkCOD(){
         var zipcode;
    var cod = $('cod').value;
    if(cod == ''){
        $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
        return
    }else{
        $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
            method:'post',
            parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                $('cod_msg').update(response);

                if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                    {
                                      zipcode='checked';
                                      jQuery('.btn-cart').prop("disabled", false);  
                                    }
                                  else
                                  {
                                  zipcode='';
                                    jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                  }

            },
            onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
        });
    }
}
```

For server side validation you can set this product is selble no and with your condition for that you can use this observer.
`catalog_product_is_salable_after` and restrict user to addtocart that product by `issalable` to `no`.

Comment: Yeah user3046689 u suggested me right. But one problem is coming.

Comment: If user add the correct zipcode after the wrong zipcode then page does not getting refresh & the button of ADD TO CART is still freezed. How to refresh the page of product.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: When you updated this Murtuza

Comment: just today I have updated this

Comment: Okzz i will check  & update you

Comment: I had checked your updated code, but i am having the same issue. When user type the wrong zipcode & click on check button, the add to cart button is getting freeze, which is good for me & when users add the correct zipcode after wrong one without refreshing the page & click on check button the message is getting displayed, but the add to cart button is still freezed.

Comment: your code does not work for me

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala like this, can i set the condition like if my Product X present in cart no other products able to add to cart and some other products already present in the cart Products X not able add to cart, the main goal is products X purchase alone. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @zus you can check all items in cart `checkout_cart_save_before` via this event and you can remove specific item from cart as per your logic